# How to get session token after successful authentication?

Tags: laravel, session-cookies, laravel-5

After successful authentication via a form post sign-in, I need to be able to use the same session token within the response to do another post to a protected route, but this time using XMLHttpRequest.

How would I get the session token, considering that the successful authentication response has already passed.

Comment: Can you clarify the relevance of "after successful authentication" to the question? Presumably the process of grabbing the session token will be the same, regardless of the authentication state associated with that session?

Comment: What I am trying to say, is that I need to access protected routes after signing in via XMLHttpRequests (without leaving the current page, but using XMLHttpRequest via javascript)

Comment: After you logged in the system (both via ajax or form submit), next request is authenticated. You dont need session token to do this.

Comment: I need to pass the session token each time, that's how the server will know who AM I..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session token is stored in a `laravel_session` cookie, assuming default Laravel settings (see `config/session.php`).

You can read the cookie in javascript using `document.cookie`. For example:

```
function readCookie(name)
{
    var matches = document.cookie.match('(^|; )'+name+'=([^;]*)');

    if (matches) {
        return decodeURIComponent(matches[2]);
    }

    return null;
}

var token = readCookie('laravel_session');
```

Comment: Then, how would I use it in the XMLHttpRequest request? shall I just store it in the request as a header entry? what would be the key name?